# Use Nokogiri to edit div tags that are not class or id

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

This is probably a really simple question, but I am very new to Nokogiri and would love to get beyond this small hurdle I have.

How can I replace the contenteditable="true" to false or remove it completely using Nokogiri?

```
<div contenteditable="true">
```

Thanks!

Comment: Probably same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610473/nokogiri-rubygem-find-and-replace-html-tags

Comment: You really need to show some code so we know that you at least tried to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set it to false:

```
doc.search('div[contenteditable=true]').each{|div| div[:contenteditable] = 'false'}
```

Remove them:

```
doc.search('div[contenteditable=true]').remove
```

Comment: I accepted this because it did the job with just that one line of code (setting it to false). The remove removed the entire div and I only wanted to remove the contenteditable="true" part.

Comment: In that case: `doc.search('div[contenteditable=true]').each{|div| div.attributes['contenteditable'].remove}`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach when you want to remove it completely using ***Nokogiri***:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse('<div contenteditable="true">')
doc.at('div') 
# => #(Element:0x504911a {
#      name = "div",
#      attributes = [
#        #(Attr:0x5048db4 { name = "contenteditable", value = "true" })]
#      })
node=doc.at('div')
node
# => #(Element:0x504911a {
#      name = "div",
#      attributes = [
#        #(Attr:0x5048db4 { name = "contenteditable", value = "true" })]
#      })

node.delete('contenteditable')
node
# => #(Element:0x504911a { name = "div" })
```

---

Here is an approach when you want to replace the `contenteditable="true"` to `false` ***Nokogiri***:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse('<div contenteditable="true">')
doc.at('div') 
# => #(Element:0x495cb2c {
#      name = "div",
#      attributes = [
#        #(Attr:0x495c88e { name = "contenteditable", value = "true" })]
#      })
node=doc.at('div')
node.to_s
# => "<div contenteditable=\"true\"></div>"
node['contenteditable']=false
node.to_s
# => "<div contenteditable=\"false\"></div>"
```

[`Nokogiri::XML::Node`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html) holds all it attributes names/values as keys/values pairs of `Hash`.Here is an example:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse('<div contenteditable="true" class = "foo">')
node=doc.at('div')
node.keys
# => ["contenteditable", "class"]
node.values
# => ["true", "foo"]
```

Thus if you want to change the value of an attribute of a node use [`Nokogiri::XML::Node#[]=`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D)(which is like [`Hash#[]=`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D)) or if you want to delete the specific attribute of that node use [`Nokogiri::XML::Node#delete`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-delete)(which is like [`Hash#delete`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-delete)).

From the comment ***How would I check to see if the div actually has the contenteditable attribute***..

Yes possible using method [`Nokogiri::XML::Node#key?`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-key-3F)

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse('<div contenteditable="true" class = "foo">')
node=doc.at('div')
node.key?('class') # => true
node.key?('foo') # => false
node.delete('class') if node.key?('class')
node.delete('class') if node.key?('foo')
node.to_s
# => "<div contenteditable=\"true\"></div>"
```

Comment: That's awesome! How would I check to see if the div actually has the contenteditable attribute? Only a few of them in the entire doc has them, and I'm guessing it will triggers errors if I try to delete them when they are not present?

Comment: Thanks so much for your in-depth descriptions!

Comment: @NicholasJohnMartin I tried to show how to write the code to meet  your need,with chunk of codes.. This will give you ideas..Now if you understand my answer,you can code your need very easily..